# Jquery async call not working on user event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my webpage many on-load ajax call those works fine.
Action takes time as per processing time. Means if any action that has been complete will send response and will not wait for first to finish.

But if same I am trying to do with on-lick or any user event. All ajax call works synchronously.  I want these should not wait to finish the execution of first running action. All should start and complete independently.

I am using jquery 1.8 where default async= true;

Please help me here to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue may be due to session lock.
more detail you can find it here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

call session_write_close  function if there no session write activity in your script or function.

Such issues are observed in many concurrent ajax call and previous call has some session write activity. In this case session will be locked until it completed its execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you set async to true, they will all fire at the same time. 
make explicitly declaration of async = true option in each ajax call .
Useful jsfiddle link

    http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/tS349/
```

Comment: I tried the same , but still not working. Onload all call works fine, user event works synchronously.